# Python reading in a sequence of numbers and combine into array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to combine a sequence of numbers into a string in the form: [width of array]. See below for examples.

Input: sequence = ['0','1','2','0','1','2','3','4']

Output:

```
A 1D array with a width of [3]
A 1D array with a width of [5]
```

Input: sequence = ['00','01','02','03','10','11','12','13','00','01','10','11']

Output:

```
A 2D array with a width of [2][4]
A 2D array with a width of [2][2]
```

Explanation: left digit being the row number of the 2D array and right digit being the column number.

```
00 -> first row, first column
01 -> first row, second column
.
.
.
13 -> second row, third column
```

I can support 1D arrays, but I have no clue how to deal with multi-dimensional arrays. You can also disregard the code below and use a whole different approach.

```
temp = 0
sequence = ['0','1','2','0','1','2','3','4']
array = ''
for i in sequence:
    if int(i) > temp:
        temp += 1
    else:
        if temp != 0:
            array = "[" + str(temp + 1) + "]"
            print(array)
            temp = 0

if temp != 0:
        array = "[" + str(temp + 1) + "]"
        print(array)
        temp = 0
```

Output:

```
[3]
[5]
```

Comment: This is a very odd requirement; are you perhaps just looking for one more than the maximum value for each string position? But that's doesn't fit with the steps you take in the third (coded) example, so I guess not...

Comment: How do you explain in words the difference between a 1d *array* and a 2d *array*? - What are the rules that define a *row* and *column* in a 2d array?

Comment: Just updated it with an explanation of the difference between a 1d and 2d array, hope it helps a bit.

Comment: You cannot define `sequence = [00,01,02,03,10,11,12,13,00,01,10,11]` in Python because of the leading zero.